# version dependency error while using screenshots package

Tags: dependency-management

Because every version of screenshots depends on YAML ^2.1.15 and flutter_piano depends on YAML ^3.0.0, screenshots are forbidden.
So, because flutter_piano depends on screenshots 2.1.0, version solving failed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.